# Is it possible to create a function taking two parameters (key-value pair of a map, preference) & delete the key-value pair if the preference is "no"?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a function that takes two parameters (key-value pair of a map, preference) and deleted the key-value pair in the map if the preference is "no"? Here's a pseudocode below to illustrate what I want to happen:

```
const myMap = new Map ()
myMap.set = (key1, value1) 
myMap.set = (key2, value2) 

function here ((key,value), preference)

If ((key,value), no) == myMap.delete (the specific key,value pair in the map) 
else (keep the key-value pair in the map)
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: How? Would you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` is an iterable object, which means you can loop over it with the `for...of` protocol. This enables you to compare values in the map to a pair that you are looking for.

Within that loop check if the pairs match up with the pairs that you want to delete. The second parameter seems trivial though as currently the only *preference* is `'No'`. So the default purpose of the function could be to just remove the pairs if they are found.

Here below you can see a function doing what you described above. Let me know if I understood you correctly and ask any questions if you have any.

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set('Snip', 'Snap');
map.set('Foo', 'Bar');
map.set('Baz', 'Faz');

const filterPair = ([keyToMatch, valueToMatch], preference) => {
  for (const [key, value] of map) {
    if (
      (key === keyToMatch) &&
      (value === valueToMatch) &&
      preference === 'No'
    ) {
      map.delete(key)
    }
  }
}

filterPair(['Foo', 'Bar'], 'No')

for (const pair of map) {
  console.log(pair)
}
```

Alternatively you could also do it without looping and using the key of the pair to select the key in the map and check if the values are matching.

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set('Snip', 'Snap');
map.set('Foo', 'Bar');
map.set('Baz', 'Faz');

const filterPair = ([key, value], preference) => {
  if (value === map.get(key) && preference === 'No') {
     map.delete(key)
  }
}

filterPair(['Foo', 'Bar'], 'No')

for (const pair of map) {
  console.log(pair)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as intended. Everything made sense to me except for the very last part: for (const pair of map) {
  console.log(pair)
} Why do we have to declare that again?

Comment: That is just to demonstrate the result of the function and can be discarded. But you have to loop the map to expose its values, so that's why there is a second loop there.